# confused about this error in printing array in python?

Tags: python, arrays, console

Consider the following code; I want to print the array Ptimes 3 spaces from the beginning of console screen. I have tried

```
print "   %s" %(Ptimes)
```

when I use this form nothing printed it says that there is error "all arguements covered due too string formatting.

the original worked code is:

```
PN = input("   Enter each process time following by its arrival time separated by comma: ")

Ptimes = PN[::2]  
Atimes = PN[1::2]
print    Ptimes
print    Atimes
```

Answer (score 1):

`Ptimes` is a tuple, and Python wants to find placeholders for each *element **in** `Ptimes`. Wrap it in a tuple (add a comma) instead:

```
print "   %s" % (Ptimes,)
```

Demo:

```
>>> Ptimes = ('foo', 'bar')
>>> print "   %s" % (Ptimes)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
>>> print "   %s" % (Ptimes,)
   ('foo', 'bar')
```